# jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter doesn't generate XML Report

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I have problem with  JunitXML reporter. It doesn't generate xml file.
I open test by: protractor example-test.js. I haven't any errors, but file doesn't generate. Please help.

```js
local.ts file

import { Config } from 'protractor';
  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
export const ENV: Config = {
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': 'ANY'
    },


    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: '/Users/test/Desktop/test2/automatic_tests/raports',
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
        }));
    } 


local.ts file
import { Config } from 'protractor';

import { ENV } from './local';

export const TestConfig: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    untrackOutstandingTimeouts: true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
    noGlobals: true,
    capabilities: ENV.capabilities,
    seleniumAddress: ENV.seleniumAddress,
    baseUrl: ENV.baseUrl,
    params: ENV.params
};


test-runner.ts
import { Config } from 'protractor';
import { TestConfig } from '../../test';

export let config: Config = TestConfig;
config.specs = ['example-test.js'];
```

Help please

Comment: Can you check if below suggestion worked?

Comment: yes it's working for me thx

Comment: Glad that it worked .. Can you mark the issue as resolved !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report will be generated. There is one small catch you are missing :)

Your `savePath` is configured incorrectly. The `reporter` determines absolute path from the relative path you provide here. You incorrectly have an `/` at zero index of your path

`savePath: '/testresults/results/blah',` will create a report in `C:\testresults\results\blah`

You also must have a report generated in C: Check once

`savePath: 'testresults/results/blah',` will create a report in `<<projectLocation>>\testresults\results\blah`